# How can I prevent Google's new image search design from hotlinking?

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect, jpeg, hotlinking

Since Google released it's new image search design, my traffic has dropped 50%.
Users simply click "View Original Image" and google takes them directly to image source.. (www.mydomain.com/image.jpg)
Is there something i can do, perhaps a redirect from a hotlinked jpg/png ?
I'm considering a htaccess block of hotlinks but this will get me de-indexed. Not sure if it's worth it yet. Google is literally stealing my bandwidth and there doesn't seem to be anything i can do about it.. :(

Help?

Comment: Check the `referrer` when serving the image?

Comment: Will it effect indexing?

Comment: The only problem with checking the referer is that Google is now sending a blank for that and mos hotlink recipes call for allowing blanks. I'd like to know how fansshare is doing their version.

Comment: Look how fansshare.com does it. I'm still figuring out it myself, otherwise I'd post all details.

Comment: @Nasmon Did you figure how they do it yet?

Comment: Hey GameDevGuru, we did ... I'm currently writing an extensive blog post about it. It's ready in about an hour and I'll immediately post the link here. Stay tuned ;-)

Comment: And here it is: http://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/hotlinking-protection-and-watermarking-for-google-32/

Comment: @Nasmon Thanks. Your method works well for pixabay. However, I'm not familiar with NGINX. Can the same results be accomplished with .htaccess file?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have missed a notification and just saw your comment :-/ I'm pretty sure, the same can be achieved in Apache (.htaccess) and LightTPD as well. Read a bit into Apache "RewriteRules" ... I'm not sure about variables inside htaccess, though. But it would surprise me, if Apache wasn't able to handle the same problems.

Comment: @Nasmon Hey so i finally got most of it working, but when i click through the watermark image or "Visit Site", it shows watermarked images. How do i fix this? Both image preview and click through have google as referrer..

Comment: We'v made a few code changes over the first few days after our blog post was published. The post has always been updated immediately, but I don't know, if you've read the latest suggestions... Please take a look at the code scheme at 3) under "Applied hotlinking protection on Pixabay". Also please note that we do need an additional GET param to make this work.

Comment: @Nasmon Yes i've been able to duplicate most of your tutorial including the GET parameter for .htaccess, but the only thing is i'm not able to distinguish click through from image preview. So the first time user visits from google all images are watermarked. How can i prevent this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain it in more detail than in our blog post. Check if it works for pixabay.com - it definitively should! That's exactly what we describe.

Comment: It has something to do with cache because once i refresh the page it shows unwatermarked image, as it should..

Comment: Okay i figured it out. Works great. Traffic climbing

Comment: @Nasmon Okay I ran accross an issue. Some images are getting indexed with watermark, I have no idea why.

Comment: As I said: follow all the steps in our post. Every single line of code has its purpose. E.g. cache control headers *MUST* set, or it won't work. Same goes for the GET param and for sending the non-watermark images to bots. Check your htaccess, if you really show the real images to the search engine bots. Possibly there's an error in your code ... maybe some typo ...

Comment: @Nasmon It's weird because new images getting indexed are good (no watermark)
but some old images are getting re-indexed with watermark. The code is exactly the same for both images..